# I deleted my windows 8.1 partition and

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

I deleted my partition for windows 8.1 and also the image file installing Ubuntu. What I wanted to do was install Ubuntu alongside Windows using half my disk space. Is there any possible way to recover windows 8.1 other than purchasing it?

*First installed OEM installer then regular version also tryin to install and run some iso files on my system

Comment: What is the make and manufacturer of your computer?

Comment: Follow user647201 post about how to install using Ubuntu Live which is easiest method in my opinion. I will add two more links to my post to help you out! ;)

Comment: See also [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/286181/22949). However, if you didn't have any important data in your Windows partition besides Windows itself (i.e., no documents or anything that you didn't have fully backed up), and if the Windows system really was damaged or destroyed, then you will be better off reinstalling Windows. It's not usually necessary to buy anything--if your computer came with Windows, you should have a way to put it back. You may want to ask on [su].

Comment: " Is there any possible way to recover windows 8.1 other than purchasing it?" Why ask us that?

Answer (score 1):

A great free and open source software that I always recommend to anyone for recovering lost partitions is [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)

There are several methods available to use TestDisk to recover your partitions. Just choose the one you find more appropriate for you from the webpage [TestDisk Livecd](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Livecd)

In addition the website also contains a [step by step guide](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) in order to help you.

Lastly don't forget that the more you use a drive after accidental deletion, the less likely you are going to be able to recover from it!

Good luck :)

Comment: How do you install TestDisk I'm like real brand new and don't know how to install after the archive manager

Answer (score 1):

When this happens shutdown and do not install or use any software.

1. Start a live CD or live usb stick of ubuntu,etc.
2. Download testdisk using live CD.
3. Install testdisk from a terminal session ie sudo ./testdisk
   (terminal can be found in the start menu)

This is taken from unallocated-space-with-important-data/24951#24951

Testdisk can be downloaded from; http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download

For instructions on how to use testdisk see; http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

Good Luck.